# Assigning array keys based on the values of another array

Tags: php, array

An optimisation question:

Currently I have entities stored in text files in the following format:

```
Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3
Value1-1,Value1-2,Value1-3
Value2-1,Value2-2,Value2-3
Value3-1,Value3-2,Value3-3
```

And convert it into a 2D array in the following format:

```
$array = array(array('Attribute1' => 'Value1-1',
                     'Attribute2', => 'Value1-2',
                     'Attribute3', => 'Value1-3'),
               array('Attribute1' => 'Value2-1',
                     'Attribute2', => 'Value2-2',
                     'Attribute3', => 'Value2-3'),
               array('Attribute1' => 'Value3-1',
                     'Attribute2', => 'Value3-2',
                     'Attribute3', => 'Value3-3'));
```

Using the following PHP code:

```
$lines = array();
$dump = normaliseNewLine($dump);
$dump = explode("\n", $dump);
$attributes = explode(',', array_shift($dump));

for($i = 0; $i < count($dump); $i++) {
    $tmp = explode(',', $dump[$i]);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($tmp); $j++) {
        $lines[$i][$attributes[$j]] = $tmp[$j];
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of completing this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP provides functions to [parse CSV files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) line-by-line.

```
$file = ...
$headers = fgetcsv($file);
$lines = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $lines[] = array_combine($headers, $line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses fewer lines, and is [slightly quicker](http://i110.photobucket.com/albums/n92/General-Jazza/TestPHP_zpsf07b8814.png) for me:

```
function($fileName)
{
    $handle = fopen($fileName, 'r');
    $attributes = fgetcsv($handle);
    for($i = 0; $line = fgetcsv($handle); $i++)
    {
        foreach($attributes as $k => $attribute)
        {
            $lines[$i][$attribute] = $line[$k];
        }
    }
    return $lines;
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that this code does not produce the correct output!

Comment: @mulquin You're right- updated the answer.